# Google Cloud BigQuery not showing SQL databases

Tags: sql-server, database, google-cloud-platform, dataset

I uploaded a SQL database to my Google Cloud instance (SQL Server 2019 Standard), which works fine now. I'm even able to connect a local Access macro to this Cloud database and manage the data in the Cloud SQL tables. Works perfect.

[Available SQL databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eib5l.png)

But Gooogle Cloud BigQuery does not show this database (which is visible in the SQL App).

[No SQL databases shown in BigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2FuC.png)

I added a dataset but I don't know how to manage the relation between this dataset and my database.
I also found that the recommended way to do that is using BigQuery Cloud SQL federated query, but this doesn't support SQL Server database, only MySql and Postgres in Google Cloud SQL service.

Any help would be appreciated.